# Fragment Webpage is not currently in the FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

i have an application contains a ViewPager that loads 3 Webpages from local HTML file, it works fine but when i try to start an intent in different activity it crashes with the following message:

```
05-15 11:33:12.533    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging E/FragmentManager﹕ Fragment Webpage{22947acd} is not currently in the FragmentManager
05-15 11:33:12.533    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging E/FragmentManager﹕ Activity state:
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ Active Fragments in 3e30ef82:
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ #0: null
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ #1: null
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ #2: null
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ Added Fragments:
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ #0: Webpage{22947acd}
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ #1: Webpage{245bc693}
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ #2: Webpage{1a4686d0}
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ FragmentManager misc state:
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ mActivity=null
05-15 11:33:12.534    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ mContainer=null
05-15 11:33:12.535    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ mCurState=0 mStateSaved=true mDestroyed=true
05-15 11:33:12.535    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/FragmentManager﹕ mAvailIndices: [0, 1, 2]
05-15 11:33:12.535    7702-7702/com.example.android.horizontalpaging D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-15 10:52:38.309    2589-2589/com.example.android.horizontalpaging E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.horizontalpaging, PID: 2589
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Webpage{3e30ef82} is not currently in the FragmentManager
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment(FragmentManager.java:571)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.saveState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:188)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onSaveInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1270)
            at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:13669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2859)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
            at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:13652)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1967)
            at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1366)
            at android.app.ActivityGroup.onSaveInstanceState(ActivityGroup.java:66)
            at android.app.TabActivity.onSaveInstanceState(TabActivity.java:112)
            at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1298)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:3958)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here's the Activity that contains ViewPager :

```
public class Azkar extends ActionBarActivity {

    public  static  SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    public static ViewPager mViewPager;
    String[] tabsTitle = {"أذكار الصباح","أذكار المساء","أذكار الصلاة"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.azkar);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3-1);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setTextSize(40);
        tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    }



    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{


        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Webpage();
                    args.putInt(Webpage.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Webpage();
                    args.putInt(Webpage.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment = new Webpage();
                    args.putInt(Webpage.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    break;
            }

            return fragment;

        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

            if(object==null)
                return POSITION_UNCHANGED;

            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabsTitle[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

    }



}
```

And this's the Webpage Fragment:

```
public class Webpage extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private WebView webView;

    public Webpage() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webpage, container, false);
        TextView pageNumber = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pageNumber);
        pageNumber.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        int number = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        String file = null;

        switch (number){
            case 0:
                file = "morning.html";
                break;
            case 1:
                file = "evning.html";
                break;
            case 2:
                file = "prayer.html";
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+file);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

hope someone will figure out a fix for this. thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you are trying get the Fragment before it is loaded, Pages in the ViewPager are loaded when them are needed.

Comment: have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041508/putfragment-fragment-x-is-not-currently-in-the-fragmentmanager)